# Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for dual pairing?

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose we have a Hilbert space $X$ and its dual $X^*$. Given a dual pairing $$_{X^*}\langle x,y\rangle_X,$$ does there exist a sort of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality so that $|\langle x, y\rangle|\leq ||x||_{X^*}||y||_{X}$?

Comment: A Hilbert space is isomorphic ti its dual/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, since $|⟨ x,y ⟩ | = |x(y)| \leq \sup_{‖z‖_X=1} |x(z)|‖y‖ = ‖x‖_{X^*}‖y‖_X   $.

Comment: Ah, pretty obvious. Thanks!

Comment: Do we actually need $X$ to be a Hilbert space or does this inequality hold for general Banach spaces?

Comment: @Alvo Yes, this is nothing but the definition of the norm of an linear functional.

Comment: You mean "Yes, it does hold for general Banach spaces"? Sorry, just want to be sure...

Comment: If you really want to be sure, you should consult the definition of the norm of a linear functional instead of trusting something a stranger wrote :) @Alvo

Comment: True :D Thanks again

Comment: Does an inequality of such sort still hold for non-linear functionals ?

Comment: @Rebellos I have no clue how to answer such a vague question, much less in a comment. Ask a new question?